# Probability of 3 friends being part of 5 person committee

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

There are $18$ students that will be forming a committee of $5$ people. The people in the committee will be picked out of a hat randomly. What is the probability that Joe, Joseph, and John will be $3/5$ members of the committee?

I've tried during various things, I know that the total number of combinations of 5 people that can be formed from $18$ is $8568$  $(18C5)$, but I'm not exactly sure what the numerator should be. I would love an explanation as to why the answer is why it is please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got one part of the answer: all of the possible committees which is $_{18}C_5$.

Now you'll need the number of committees that have Joe, Joseph, and John.

As a hint, you know three of the five committee members -- Joe, Joseph, and John -- so you only need to choose two from who's left.

Can you take it from here?

> After picking Joe, Joseph, and John, there are $15$ left, and we need to pick two, which is $_{15}C_2$. So the probability is $(_{15}C_2)/(_{18}C_5)$.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine $5$ "committee" slots and $13$ other slots.
We want all $3 J's$ to be in the committee,
so $Pr = \dfrac5{18}\dfrac4{17}\dfrac3{16} = \dfrac5{408}$

Answer (score 0):

You already have @John's 'hidden' answer (+1). Here are
two different methods. Now is the time to consider
how you can confidently get the next such problem correct without help.

*Simulation in R:* If the three J's are numbered 1,2, and 3 out of 18,
then simulation of a million such draws gives the answer
correct to about 3 places:

```
set.seed(2021)
students = 1:18
jjj = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(students, 5)<=3))
mean(jjj == 3)
[1] 0.012278
```

*Hypergeometric geometric probability:* There are 3 red chips and 15 black chips in an urn
and three are drawn at random without replacement,
what is the probability all three drawn are red?

```
dhyper(3, 3,15, 5)
[1] 0.0122549
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me!